# How to test file permissions using node.js?

Tags: file, node.js, permissions

How can I check to see the permissions (read/write/execute) that a running node.js process has on a given file?

I was hoping that the [`fs.Stats` object](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) had some information about permissions but I don't see any.  Is there some built-in function that will allow me to do such checks?  For example:

```javascript
var filename = '/path/to/some/file';
if (fs.canRead(filename)) // OK...
if (fs.canWrite(filename)) // OK...
if (fs.canExecute(filename)) // OK...
```

Surely I don't have to attempt to open the file in each of those modes and handle an error as the negative affirmation, right?  There's got to be a simpler way...

Comment: I think there is no api function for that.

Comment: Actually, just going ahead and trying to open the file and handling any arising errors is usually the correct approach. You _can_ test if the file is readable, but it involves more effort (even if it is hidden in the core libraries, the work is still performed).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am late, but, I was looking for same reasons as yours and learnt about this.

[`fs.access`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback) is the one you need. It is available from node v0.11.15.

```
function canWrite(path, callback) {
  fs.access(path, fs.W_OK, function(err) {
    callback(null, !err);
  });
}

canWrite('/some/file/or/folder', function(err, isWritable) {
  console.log(isWritable); // true or false
});
```

Answer (score 7):

There is [fs.accessSync(path[, mode])](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_accesssync_path_mode) nicely mentioned:

> Synchronously tests a user's permissions for the file or directory specified by path. The mode argument is an optional integer that specifies the accessibility checks to be performed. Check File Access Constants for possible values of mode. It is possible to create a mask consisting of the bitwise OR of two or more values (e.g. fs.constants.W_OK | fs.constants.R_OK).
>
> If any of the accessibility checks fail, an Error will be thrown. Otherwise, the method will return undefined.

Embeded example:

```
try {
  fs.accessSync('etc/passwd', fs.constants.R_OK | fs.constants.W_OK);
  console.log('can read/write');
} catch (err) {
  console.error('no access!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking readability is not so straightforward as languages like PHP make it look by abstracting it in a single library function. A file might be readable to everyone, or only to its group, or only to its owner; if it is not readble to everybody, you will need to check if you are actually a member of the group, or if you are the owner of the file. It is usually much easier and faster (not only to write the code, but also to execute the checks) to try to open the file and handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

I Implemented a helper function which you can await.

The code:

```
function checkFolderPermission (path) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        fs.access(path, fs.constants.X_OK || fs.constants.R_OK || fs.constants.W_OK, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                resolve(false);
            } else {
                resolve(true);
              }
        })
    })
}
```

This checks for Read, Write and Execute permission.

Answer (score -3):

How about using a [child process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)?

```
var cp = require('child_process');

cp.exec('ls -l', function(e, stdout, stderr) {
  if(!e) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    // process the resulting string and check for permission
  }
});
```

Not sure though if *process* and *child_process* share the same permissions.

Comment: `fs.Stats` objects already provide a `mode` property, there is no need to exec an external process; besides, the permissions of the file do not magically change depending on who's looking

Comment: @lanzz, if the process runs under a different user context, it would have different rights regarding file access

Comment: How would a child process run under a different user context?