# How to check the access rights of a folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to process some directories under a specific path. one of the directories contains some folders. actually, i do not have
access to all these folders, because some of them are my own and the others belong to other users.

my question is, is there any way in javascript to check the access rights of a specific folder? because what I want to do is, to check first if I have 
access to open and see the contents of that folder or not. if I have access to it, then the logic will continue. if i do not have the right to open that
folder, then i will do something else.

please let me know how to check the my access rights of a folder or a file

**Note**:

I am using Ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test file permissions using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088544/how-to-test-file-permissions-using-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.access(__dirname, fs.constants.R_OK, function(err) {
  if(err){
    console.error("can't read");
    process.exit(1);
  }

  console.log("can read");
  process.exit(0);
});
```

same way you can check for write and executable access

you can find the documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fs` for your task

```
var file= 'test.text'

// Check if the file exists in the current directory.
fs.access(file, fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
  console.log(`${file} ${err ? 'does not exist' : 'exists'}`);
});

// Check if the file is readable.
fs.access(file, fs.constants.R_OK, (err) => {
  console.log(`${file} ${err ? 'is not readable' : 'is readable'}`);
});

// Check if the file is writable.
fs.access(file, fs.constants.W_OK, (err) => {
  console.log(`${file} ${err ? 'is not writable' : 'is writable'}`);
});

// Check if the file exists in the current directory, and if it is writable.
fs.access(file, fs.constants.F_OK | fs.constants.W_OK, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(
      `${file} ${err.code === 'ENOENT' ? 'does not exist' : 'is read-only'}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`${file} exists, and it is writable`);
  }
});
```

[More](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback) details